# How can I implement this recursive formula?

Tags: python, recursion, probability, indicator

[Photo Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfDnT.png)

```
def prob(i, r, b): #r and b may be np.arrays or lists()
    if i == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return (1 / i) * #And what's next?
```

Formula denotes unnormalized probability probability P(i) - the probability that the system is in state i, wherein and P(0) = 1, where I() - [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), b_k and r_k - const parameters, which fed to the  input. I don't know how I can implement this code. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: What is your probability distribution? What is your `I` distribution? Your question is utterly vague.

Comment: The idea behind recursive functions is that they call themselfes given a certain condition. Where do you want to involve `r` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

```py
def prob(i, rs, bs): # i: int, rs: [num], bs: [num]:
    # I not know if the elems in rs are integers, neither positives
    # I apply abs in rs elems and compare with equals and less
    if i <= 0:
        return 1
    return (1 / i) * sum(b * prop(i - abs(r)) for (r, b) in zip(rs, bs))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! But how can I should use the indicator function in the code?

Comment: I'm not know how is this indicator function, sorry. I read your question, but i'm not undestand.

Comment: Daniel, if inner expression of indicator function is True, then indicator function is equal to 1, and 0 in the other case.